# Unlocked package installation with Person Account and Community enabled

Tags: community, salesforcedx, person-accounts, unlocked-package

If we have 2 sandboxes and if we enable Person Account and create community in Sandbox1 and create an unlocked package with some components, please let me know if it is a prerequisite to enable Person Account and enable community in Sandbox2 before installing the unlocked package in Sandbox2? We are not using Scratch orgs.

Thanks..

Comment: I believe it depends on the package itself, if you don't use features of person accounts (such as __pc fields) or community. In the end an unmanaged package is just like a change-set

Comment: Do you mean to say if we have Person Account/Community enabled in Sandbox1 then the same need to be enabled in Sandbox2 before the package is installed? Or do we have something like below to be included in scratch org definition file:                           "features": ["Communities"]    I have read that this needs to be done if we use scratch orgs. Not sure if the same needs to be done for sandbox because we are not using scratch orgs.

Comment: Only if your package uses things that add the dependency (__pc fields, PersonAccount recordTypes, community-related components)